# sounds getting clipped when playing more then two different sounds at once

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to build a drum kit web app in which a certain key is certain drum. When I'm playing two different sounds while the first one isn't done it works fine, it's just finishing both sounds and stops as it should do.

When I'm trying to play the third sound while the first two didn't yet finished, it just scrambles them all and none are sounding as should be.

```
function playSound(event) {
    var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
    if (keyPressed === 65) {
        audio.hihat.currentTime = 0;
        audio.hihat.cloneNode(true).play();
    } else if (keyPressed === 83) {
        audio.snare.currentTime = 0;
        audio.snare.play();
    } else if (keyPressed === 81) {
        audio.crash.currentTime = 0;
        audio.crash.play();
    } else if (keyPressed === 87) {
        audio.tom01.currentTime = 0;
        audio.tom01.play();
    } else if (keyPressed === 69) {
        audio.tom02.currentTime = 0;
        audio.tom02.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript by default will only allow you to play one sound at a time, and will not play the next sound until it is registered as completed. To save yourself some footwork, the `howler.js` library makes it very easy to solve the exact problem you've described.

Sounds can be used as the source of a `howl` object. Here's a snippet from their [official documentation.](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#examples)

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.mp3']
});
```

Then, your sound can be played like so.

```
sound.play();
```

[Here is an example](https://sureto96.github.io/TapTap) of a project which I utilized `howler.js` to allow overlapping sounds. I believe this is the effect you are looking for with your drum kit.

Here's how I laid it out in my app:

```
sound: new Howl({
            src: ['Assets/bubbles.mp3']
            })
```

Then, when I execute my event (which in my case is a key press), I call the howl.

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    sound.play();
```

There's some extra pieces I used in my project as I was also using the `Paper.js` library as well, but I just wanted to give you the general idea of how `howler.js` works without veering too far away from the scope of your question.

The official website where you can download `howler.js` is [here.](https://howlerjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use howler.js which is a powerful tool for audio sounds. Or you can use useSound Hook if your project is React-based. useSound hook uses howler.js under the hood and has extra functionalities like avoiding overlapping